# Why ContextMenu is not visible in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, layout, android-contextmenu

Hello I have a problem in show a context menu.
I have this methods to implement my menu:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

But when I run the emulator and holds the Menu key, I don't see my context menu.
I am using a simple layout, without listviews. I dont understand what view I can choose to register my context menu.

Anyone can explain me this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `registerForContextMenu(View v)` and pass in your layout view as the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

if you want create menu then follow this [link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) and `Menu` and `ContextMenu` both are diffrent in android.. menu is open on menu button of device and contextmenu is open in widget like as on listview,textview...etc